# IDA Pro getting division by zero when trying to debug assault cube

Tags: ida

I'm new to IDA and I am trying to debug a game using win32. When it starts up though I get a division by zero error then it crashes. Any help would be awesome!

Comment: Does that exception happen inside IDA or inside the debuggee? As a side-note: *you* know what you're dealing with, but you give us little to help you. Perhaps you should use the [site help](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/help) to learn what can be asked (within the scope of this site) and how to ask.

Answer (score 2):

*short question yields short answer*

This is probably happening because of anti debugging techniques used by the program. By detecting and nullifying  the anti-debugging techniques you can safely avoid the exception and crash.

Comment: I don't think so. IDA *looks* at code, it does not *execute* it. This sounds more like a Tech Support type of question – for example, a bad or missing font that IDA may be expecting to draw its interface with.

Comment: @usr2564301 IDA has a debugger and OP explicitly states multiple times he's debugging using IDA...

Comment: IDA has even *several* debugger backends and even allows for remote debugging. Frankly I prefer it whenever I don't have the source to something available. Otherwise I prefer WinDbg and x64dbg and then with some space the VS debugger follows ...

Answer (score 2):

IDA debugger for win32 is pretty unstable, especially when you load a big file into ida (bigger than 20 mb), and then try to debug it. You can try attaching to a running process from IDA, instead of loading exe for disassembly first. Also, I would suggest trying the other debugging backends like Windbg (Debugger - Select debugger menu). You'll need debugging tools for Windows. And if there's no specific need to debug from IDA, then use Windbg directly.

Comment: That's a pretty generic statement. For starters I've *never* had the instability issues you describe and then given you're making such a claim you might want to point out the version of IDA you're running as well as the backend *you* are using.

Comment: If you want to experience some problems try loading chrome_child.dll and then start debugging. It's going to die trying to relocate the image. IDA x64 version survives this, x86 - dies.